# Webview show image from assets

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uno-platform

I'm trying to use a `WebView` to show some custom generated html which tries to show images that're included as assets.

Currently, I'm only interested in getting this to work in the Android head. (In the UWP head, I was using a `RichTextBlock` to accomplish the same thing. But the control `InlineUIContainer` isn't available in Uno yet.)

In the Android head, I've set the Build Action for these images to `AndroidAsset` (the images are located in the directory `Assets`)

I've tried to reference these images in the following ways from the (on the spot) generated html:

```
<img src="imgName.png" />
<img src="ms-appdata:///imgName.png" />
<img src="ms-appdata:///local/imgName.png" />
<img src="file:///imgName.png" />
```

None of these work.
I've also tried to write the html to a local file (instead of using `NavigateToString`) and navigating to that, but to no avail.

According to 'the google', the way to do this in Xamarin with its `WebView` is by using `LoadDataWithBaseUrl(null, ...)`, but that method is not available in UWP/Uno's WebView...

Answer (score 0):

The `LoadDataWithBaseUrl` method is a method of the native `Android.Webkit.WebView`. This is created internally by Uno's `WebView` (which mimics the API of the UWP `WebView`).

The native `WebView` isn't exposed directly, but you can access it easily:

XAML:

```xml
<Page x:Class="WebViewTest.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="XamlWebView" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
#if !NETFX_CORE
using Uno.UI;
#endif
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WebViewTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
#if __ANDROID__
            var nativeWebView = XamlWebView.FindFirstChild<Android.Webkit.WebView>();
            nativeWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, ...)
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you can apply the approach you describe.

Comment: `FindFirstChild` keeps returning `null` for me. (Calling `GetChildren()` returns 0 items as well)

Comment: At what moment are you calling it? It needs to be after the template has materialized (eg from `Loaded`). You can also try calling `XamlWebView.ApplyTemplate()` first to ensure it's materialized.

Comment: Running it from the `Loaded` event, even after calling `ApplyTemplate` first, still no children found...